# Find path of python_notebook.ipynb when running it with Google Colab

Tags: python, path, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, getcwd

I want to find the cwd where my CODE file is stored.

With jupiter Lab i would do:

```py
import os 
cwd= os.getcwd()
print (cwd)
OUT: 
'C:...\\Jupiter_lab_notebooks\\CODE'
```

However,if i copy the folders to my GoogleDrive, and run the notebook in GOOGLE COLAB, i get:

```py
import os 
cwd= os.getcwd()
print (cwd)
OUT: 
/content
```

No matter where my notebook is stored.
How do i find the actual path my .ipynb folder is stored in?

#EDIT

What i am looking for is python code that will return the location of the COLAB notebook no matter where in drive it is stored. This way i can navigate to sub-folders from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem has been bothering me for a while, this code should set the working directory if the notebook has been singularly found, limited to Colab system and mounted drives, this can be run on Colab:

```
import requests
import urllib.parse
import google.colab
import os

google.colab.drive.mount('/content/drive')


def locate_nb(set_singular=True):
    found_files = []
    paths = ['/']
    nb_address = 'http://172.28.0.2:9000/api/sessions'
    response = requests.get(nb_address).json()
    name = urllib.parse.unquote(response[0]['name'])

    dir_candidates = []

    for path in paths:
        for dirpath, subdirs, files in os.walk(path):
            for file in files:
                if file == name:
                    found_files.append(os.path.join(dirpath, file))

    found_files = list(set(found_files))

    if len(found_files) == 1:
        nb_dir = os.path.dirname(found_files[0])
        dir_candidates.append(nb_dir)
        if set_singular:
            print('Singular location found, setting directory:')
            os.chdir(dir_candidates[0])
    elif not found_files:
        print('Notebook file name not found.')
    elif len(found_files) > 1:
        print('Multiple matches found, returning list of possible locations.')
        dir_candidates = [os.path.dirname(f) for f in found_files]

    return dir_candidates

locate_nb()
print(os.getcwd())
```

Comment: ok so it is walking though every path until it matches the filename, thanks

Comment: I wish there was a better way to do so

Answer (score 2):

Google colab allows you to save notebooks to google drive and when you create a new notebook, you can click "Locate in drive" in the file menu to access this location.

[image]

Please note, that you can mount your drive to a colab instance which means you can access the google drive as a sub-folder in the colab instance, however, if you are looking for the physical location in your **local google drive folder** (created by google drive app) then this should be something like this location (on Mac).

```
/Volumes/GoogleDrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/
```

If however, you have **mounted your google drive on your colab**, and are looking for where the notebooks are saved, via google colab, try this -

```
path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks'
```

Comment: Sorry i wasn't clear with my question: 
What i am looking for is python code that will return the location of the COLAB notebook no matter where in drive it is stored. This way i can navigate to sub-folders from there. (eg a data folder )

Answer (score 0):

Since GoogleDrive is your current working directory, you need to mount it from colab first:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive/')
```

then you need to change your directory to where your `.ipynb` stored:

```
import os 
os.chdir('/content/drive/MyDrive/path/to/your/folder')
```

Finally, if you do

```
import os 
cwd= os.getcwd()
print (cwd)
```

you will get something like `/content/drive/MyDrive/path/to/your/folder` where your `.ipynb` is stored.

And when you do

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_output(['ls'])
```

you will see your notebook file listed there.

If you want to navigate to sub-folders, just use `os.chdir()`.

Comment: So there is no way of finding the path : '/content/drive/MyDrive/path/to/your/folder'? 
a command like "get path of current notebook".

Comment: I think that is `os.getcwd()` actually doing, right?

Comment: Yes, however when you mount your drive you and run os.getcwd() you get '/content/' no matter what folder your notebook started in your google drive. 
I want to RUN a nobetook and find out in what subfolder of google drive it is stored - this way i can then navigate relative to that fodler, so that if I move the set of folders where the notebook is, everything still works