# A good way to locate colab Notebook (from code inside colab notebook)

Tags: google-colaboratory

Colab code runs on a temporarily allocated machine, thus the running environment is not aware of the notebook location on Google Drive.

I am wondering if there is an API which colab provides, which I may invoke programatically, which could tell me the location of colab notebook in Google Drive (I can manually do it by clicking on: file > Locate in drive, but I need to do this via code in Colab). This would be useful to save the data generated by my code.

Of course I can hard code this path (after mounting the gDrive), but each time, I would need to update it, and if I forget it can even overwrite the previous data. Is there a way where it could be automatically detected? It seems this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71438046/1953366 is walking though every path until it matches the filename, which is not efficient and also will fail in case I have same file name at different location.

Any better solution(s)?